# Uploaded video gets random name instead of getting the name I defined on laravel

Tags: laravel, video, file-upload

video not getting my defined name and this my name making a folder instead of making the video name. and this folder getting the video with a random name.

Controller Code:

```
 public function uploadVideo(Request $request){ 
      $this->validate($request,[
        'video' => 'required|mimes:mpeg,ogg,mp4,webm,3gp,mov,flv,avi,wmv,ts',
    ]);
    $video_upload = $request->file('video');
    $update = Page::findOrfail(1);
    if(isset($video_upload))
    {

        $videoName  = 'video'.'.'.$video_upload->getClientOriginalExtension();

        if(!Storage::disk('public')->exists('page'))
        {
            Storage::disk('public')->makeDirectory('page');
        }
        
        Storage::disk('public')->put('page/'.$videoName,$video_upload);
    } else {
        $videoName = $update->video;
    }

    $update->video = $videoName;
    $update->save();
    Toastr::success('Video Successfully Updated :)','Success');
    return redirect()->back();
         
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can use random string as video name :

```
 $videoName  = Str::random(10).'.'.$video_upload->getClientOriginalExtension();
```

and use **putFileAs** method for custom file name :

```
Storage::disk('public')->putFileAs('page',$video_upload,$videoName)
```

Comment: I think there is a problem with this line:Storage::disk('public')->put('page/'.$videoName,$video_upload);